# Question Regarding Riemann Mapping Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked this question and I think the Riemann mapping theorem can be used.

Let $D_1=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{a\},$ where $a\in \mathbb{C}$. Is there a map $f$ that maps $D_1$ analytically onto the unit disk? If yes, find such a map.

Also, the same question for $D_2=\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,\infty)$.

My thought:

The answer would be 'yes' if both $D_1$ and $D_2$ are simply connected, which is the condition in Riemann mapping theorem. However, I am not sure if it is the case.

If $D_1$ and/or $D_2$ is not simply connected, then we cannot use the Riemann mapping theorem. In this case, I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: $D_2$ is simply connected while for $D_1$ show that any holomorphic bounded map on it is constant (hint Liouville!) so in particular, cannot be onto

Comment: Can you give me an example for such a function on $D_2?$ Also, are you saying that $D_1$ is actually the whole complex plane? If possible, can you compose an answer? Thank you.

Comment: put an answer, no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for $D_1$ any bounded holomorphic function $f$ extends to the full plane since the isolated singularity at $a$ is removable; by Liouville, $f$ is constant so cannot be onto any open set.

$D_2$ is simply connected and to find a Riemann map one can use that the (rotated) Koebe function $K(z)=\frac{z}{(1+z)^2}$ is a Riemann map from the unit disc to the plane from which we remove the ray $[1/4,\infty)$ so $K-1/4$ is a Riemann map from the unit disc to $D_2$ and its inverse, of course, sends $D_2$ onto the unit disc conformally